# Monte Carlo tree search

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tree, montecarlo

I'm currently working on a MCTS implementation for a simple board game.
I think I almost got it right, but whenever I want to iterate more than 1 time
(time or number(i) as factor for iterations) the game freezes. I would be glad if someone has a solid idea about what the issue could be.

```
 // method to find  best turn
    Node findBest( )
    {
        Node startingPoint = new Node();
        startingPoint.CurrentField_Boxes = GameBoard.boxs;
        startingPoint.CurrentField_H = GameBoard.horizontal_line;
        startingPoint.CurrentField_V = GameBoard.vertical_line;

        Node rootNode = startingPoint;

       for( int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            //Selection
            Node promisingNode = selectPromisingNode(rootNode);
            Debug.Log("POST SELECTION CHECK VON X/Y " + promisingNode.x + "/" + promisingNode.y);

            //Expansion
            if (!checkField())
            {
                expandNode(promisingNode);
            }

            //Simulation
            Node nodeToExplore = promisingNode;
            Debug.Log("POST 2 SELECTION CHECK VON X/Y " + nodeToExplore.x + "/" + nodeToExplore.y);

            if (promisingNode.getChildren().Count > 0)
            {
                //get random child node
                nodeToExplore = promisingNode.getRandomChild();
                Debug.Log("POST 3 SELECTION CHECK VON X/Y " + nodeToExplore.x + "/" + nodeToExplore.y);
            }

            int playoutResult = simulation(nodeToExplore);
            Debug.Log("SIM RESULT :" + playoutResult);
            //backpropagation
            backPropogation(nodeToExplore);
        }

        Debug.Log("*********************************");
        Node  bestNode = new Node();
        Debug.Log("POST 4 SELECTION CHECK VON X/Y " + rootNode.getBestChild().x + "/" + rootNode.getBestChild().y);
        bestNode = rootNode.getBestChild();
        return bestNode;
    }

    private Node selectPromisingNode(Node rootNode)
    {
        Debug.Log("SELECTING");
        Node node = new Node();
        node = rootNode;

        while (node.getChildren().Count != 0) // checking if terminal
        {
            findBestNodeWithUCT(node);
        }

        return node;
    }

    Node findBestNodeWithUCT( Node root)
    {
        double j = 0;
        int bestIndex = 0; ;

        for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildren().Count; i++)
        {
            if (root.getChildren()[i].getVisitTimes() / root.getChildren()[i].getResult() > j)
            {
                j = root.getChildren()[i].getVisitTimes() / root.getChildren()[i].getResult();
                bestIndex = i;
                Debug.Log("BEST INDEX : " + bestIndex);
            }
        }

        Node bestOption = root.getChildren()[bestIndex];
        Debug.Log("BEST OPTION RETURN X/Y : " + bestOption.x + "/" + bestOption.y);

        return bestOption;
    }

    private void expandNode(Node node)
    {
        Debug.Log("Start EXPANSION");
        bool vert = false;
        bool hori = false;

    //Phase I : creating new Node
        //create a new node wit certain action A
        Node newNode = new Node();
        //init and setting parent 
        newNode.parent[0] = node;
        //init gamefield into node
        newNode.CurrentField_V = node.CurrentField_V;
        newNode.CurrentField_H = node.CurrentField_H;
        //init and setting child parent relationship
        newNode.visitTimes++;
        Debug.Log("ERSTELLE NEUEN KNOTEN");

     //Phase II : Validating Action
        //create a action a which leads to the expansion
        int x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,4);
        int y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 4);
        //checking variables for valid coordinates
        Debug.Log("AKTION A IN EXPANSION :" + x + y);
        //Prechecking of generated coordinates to set corresponding obj
        if (y < 3)
        {
            vert = true;
        }
        if (x < 3 )
        {
            hori = true;
        }
        else if (x == 3 && y == 3)
        {
            Debug.Log(" OUT OF BOUNDS :NEW RANDOM");
            expandNode(node);

        }

     //Phase III : Doing Action
        if(vert && newNode.CurrentField_V[x, y].tag == "is play" && hori && newNode.CurrentField_H[x, y].tag != "is play")
        {
            expandNode(node);
        }
        //setting choice into sim gamefield with green color
        if (vert && newNode.CurrentField_V[x, y].tag != "is play")// && GameBoard.sim_vertical_line[x, y].tag != "is play")
        {
            Debug.Log("SETZEN DER VERTIKALEN AKTION IN KNOTENSTATE");
            GameBoard.sim_vertical_line[x, y].tag = "is play";
            GameBoard.sim_vertical_line[x, y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = greenV;
          //  newNode.CurrentField_V[x, y].tag = "is play";
            newNode.x = x;
            newNode.y = y;
            node.nodeChildren.Add(newNode);

        }
        if (hori && newNode.CurrentField_H[x, y].tag != "is play" )//&& GameBoard.sim_horizontal_line[x, y].tag != "is play")
        {
            Debug.Log("SETZEN DER HORIZONTALEN AKTION IN KNOTENSTATE");
            GameBoard.sim_horizontal_line[x, y].tag = "is play";
            GameBoard.sim_horizontal_line[x, y].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = greenH;
          //  newNode.CurrentField_H[x, y].tag = "is play";
            newNode.x = x;
            newNode.y = y;
            node.nodeChildren.Add(newNode);

        }
        else { expandNode(node); }
    }

    private void backPropogation(Node nodeToExplore)
    {
        Node tempNode = nodeToExplore;
        Debug.Log("BACKPROPAGATION");
        while (tempNode != null)
        {
            int i = 0;

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                tempNode.visitTimes++;
                int j = tempNode.result;
                tempNode.setResult(j);
                tempNode = tempNode.getParent();
            }
            else if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                tempNode.visitTimes++;
                int j = tempNode.result;
                tempNode.setResult(j * -1);
                tempNode = tempNode.getParent();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

One iteration works fine and I already got a better behaviour than on a random bot, but with only about 5-6 nodes max can get created in one iteration.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the `selectPromisingNode()` function, you have an infinite loop starting from your second iteration. You start out plugging the root node into that function. Starting from the second iteration, the root node has more than 0 children, so the condition of the while-loop is satisfied. Inside the loop, you do not change the value of the `node` variable, so you'll infinitely often keep calling `findBestNodeWithUCT()` with the root node as argument.

You'll probably want to change that line of code inside the loop to: `node = findBestNodeWithUCT(node)`, so that you actually start traversing the tree a bit instead of staying stuck at the root.

I didn't check the rest of the code, so I do not know if there are more errors, but this at least seems to precisely explain the problem you're experiencing